# What does `nord` mean in the context of a command line prompt?

Tags: terminal, zsh, iterm2, oh-my-zsh

I updated my Powershell10K configuration with oh-my-zsh and I now sometimes get the message `nord` on the right-side of my terminal prompt. I have no idea what it is / the right terminology to use to google my question. Here's an example image:

[image]

I'd really appreciate if anyone could point me in the right direction.

### Edit

Here is the output of `print $RPROMPT`:

```
${(e)_p9k_t[4]}${${:-${_p9k_bg::=NONE}${_p9k_i::=0}${_p9k_sss::=%f}}+}${${:-${P9K_CONTENT::=${(Q)${:-"\~"}}}${_p9k_n::=}${${${_p9k_bg:-0}:#NONE}:-${_p9k_n::=25}}${_p9k_n:=${${(M)${:-x004}:#x($_p9k_bg|${_p9k_bg:-0})}:+27}}${_p9k_n:=28}${P9K_VISUAL_IDENTIFIER::=}${_p9k_v::="${P9K_VISUAL_IDENTIFIER// }"%b%K{004}%F{254}}${_p9k_c::="${P9K_CONTENT}"}${_p9k_e::=${${__p9k_s_dir+00}:-${${(%):-$_p9k_c%1(l.1.0)}[-1]}${${(%):-$_p9k_v%1(l.1.0)}[-1]}}}}+}${${_p9k_e:#00}:+${${_p9k_t[$_p9k_n]/<_p9k_ss>/$_p9k_ss}/<_p9k_s>/$_p9k_s}${_p9k_v}${${(M)_p9k_e:#11}:+ }${_p9k_c}%b%K{004}%F{254} ${${:-${_p9k_s::=%F{004}}${_p9k_ss::=|}${_p9k_sss::=%F{004}}${_p9k_i::=1}${_p9k_bg::=004}}+}}%b%k$_p9k_sss%b%k%f${:-" %b%k%f"}${${COLUMNS::=$_p9k_clm}+}
```

Comment: Is it this?  https://github.com/coltondick/zsh-dircolors-nord

Comment: I don't believe so. I'm not using that or anything related to the nord theme @Dai

Comment: What's in your `~/.oh-my-zsh/custom/plugins` ?

Comment: `example` and `zsh-autosuggestions` @Dai

Comment: Do you use NordVPN, by any chance? That could be your local host name in `RPROMPT`.

Comment: @chepner nope but thank you for the idea

Comment: What is the value of `RPROMPT` in your shell (`print "$RPROMPT"`)?

Comment: @chepner just updated question

Answer (score 1):

`nord` on the right side of your prompt means you are currently connected to VPN via NordVPN. It should also indicate the region you are connected. I suppose you've cropped the image so the region is not visible.

If you don't want to see the NordVPN indicator, open `~/.p10k.zsh`, search for `nordvpn` and comment out the first hit.

I also highly recommend installing [the recommended font](https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k/blob/master/font.md) and running `p10k configure`. Once you do that, "nord" in your prompt will be replaced with an icon. This saves space and, once you get used to the icons, is faster to parse with your eyes.

Answer (score 0):

Judging from your prompt string, you mean [Powerlevel10k](https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k) (and not "Powershell10K").

Powerlevel10k has [lots of prompt sections](https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k#batteries-included) that it shows only "on demand". In your case, it's impossible to tell what "nord" in your prompt refers to, because you have disabled both icons *and* labels in your Powerlevel10k config.

To fix this, run

```
p10k configure
```

on your command line and then choose an option that shows icons or, failing that, in the "Prompt Flow" step, choose "Fluent" (instead of "Concise").